# Alternative to returning data from functions in C++

Tags: c++, zeromq

I have a C++ program that takes in data using a [ZMQ](https://zeromq.org/) socket and processes it using many functions/submodules.

This is what I intend to do:

[image]

Such that the results can be returned to the data provider using the same socket.

The problem is that as the results are computed in the last step but I don't want to return it using the same *long* pipeline; there are already many call by references and values being used. Adding this would only complicate my system.

I could have used a global variable (`vector` for instance) and then fill it with the results. `main()` could similarly access it and globally. Due to some limitations in my knowledge of zmq, I am only able to send simple data structures like an array and not STL structures. But arrays size cannot be computed beforehand as it is result dependent. Hence, I cannot access it globally.

What alternatives do I have ?

Comment: ***Adding this would only complicate my system*** how?

Comment: "I could have used a global variable". There is no reason to. Return values from functions. It does not complicate anything. "and not STL structures". It is unclear how this problem has anything to do with the long pipeline, but there is a simple array inside every `std::vector`, so you can use `std::vector` anywhere you need an array.

Comment: If you don't want to return the value in cascade, you might provide a functor (in cascade too, but the other way) which does the expected work on the result.

Comment: A third alternative is to `throw` your result and `catch` it in `main`

Comment: @Caleth that would mean to `throw` result array from `postprocess()` (IDK if its possible to throw a 1D/2D array) and `catch` in `main()`. Is that possible between functions ?

Comment: @kiner_shah the result array size is not predetermined and is only decided when the result is computed. *Complication* arises when I try to circumvent this problem by passing STL containers or by fixing the array size in the beginning.

Comment: You can throw any (moveable) object, and catch anywhere up the stack. that's kind of the point of exceptions. If you so wish you can create a `class results_ready : public std::exception { int data[10][1000]; /* or w/e */ };` to wrap your results

Comment: @PeDro, what complication? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think chaining calls like that is beneficial. Your `pre-process()` shouldn't think where it result goes; it shouldn't know anything about `infer()` and call it; neither should `infer()` know about `post-process()`. The regular approach is to use a "superstructure" that composites the calls.

In the simplest version it will be something like:

```
pipe += post_process( infer( pre_process( get_record( pipe ) ) ) ) ;
```

More likely, it will be a sequence with temporary storage of the intermediate results, so that you could peek into them with debugger and report progress.

```
raw_record = get_record( pipe );
pre_processed = pre_process( raw_record );
inference = infer( pre_processed );
result = post_process( inference );
pipe = combine_inputs( pipe, result );
```

In more advanced cases it will be some sort of dynamic queue of 'processor' functions, so that you can assemble it from various pre-processors, infer/analyze functions and post-processors, at run-time.

Each function takes its input, returns its output, and it's not its business what happens with it. You have a separate procedure that takes care of handling the correct data flow between them.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why you suggest `combine_inputs`; The pipe/pipeline has a common socket for receiving (input data) and transmitting (result). For e.g., the input is an image array while the output is a smaller 2x2 array.

Comment: @PeDro The arrow back to main() suggests a closed-loop operation, output combined with input. If that's not the case, just skip that step.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the cascaded returns as you all suggested. As I had multiple variables to return, I used a `struct` to accommodate them and return together.